# Server Sent Event Comment with Quarkus/RestEasy/javax-ws

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy, server-sent-events

I would like to send comments from a [quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) server to a [server-sent event](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#server-sent-event-sse-support) client as a keepalive.
The specification of [SSE](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#server-sent-event-sse-support) (Server Side Event) defines an event to consist of any combination of `comment` or `field`.
I don't see any way to just send a comment. There's a [`OutboundSseEventImpl`](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.11.0.Final/independent-projects/resteasy-reactive/server/runtime/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/reactive/server/jaxrs/OutboundSseEventImpl.java) available, in the current version of the `resteasy-reactive` dependency, but if I send one with only the `comment` property given, I get a `data`-field with a big JSON containing the given `comment` as a key.

What I want to send out is something like this:

- Avery 30 seconds (or perhaps 60 seconds) I sent our a `keepalive` comment.
- When ever there's new data available, it's sent directly.

It could look like this:

```
data: {"some": "data"}

data: {"other": "data"}

:keepalive

:keepalive
```

Is there a way to sent out comments?

It looks to me, like this is not (yet?) implemented. Perhaps this is also not a [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) question, but a [RESTEasy](https://resteasy.dev/)- or a [JAX-RS](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311)-one, as those libraries are used by [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/).

Comment: I found a [ServerSentEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/ServerSentEvent.html) implementation for Spring, but I'd like to go with Quarkus and not Spring.